# Local Machine wide Visual Studio RootSuffix registration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integration

I have read so many articles about integration and yet i did not found solution for my problem. I want to integrate my VS Package to custom RootSuffix, but this integration should be common for whole machine and not only for current user. Is it possible at all ?

Beforehand thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have diged deeper into this and it seem that there is no way in Visual Studio 2010 to do machine wide suffix installation. For now machine wide installation is available only in main VS hive and suffix installation can only be performed "user wide"